# How would I detect a file with task scheduler

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I'm just wondering. Is it possible for task scheduler to detect a file? The closest thing I found to this question was on [Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/387ff0bc-c3b1-4c58-84c5-76f0f54d13f0/how-to-use-windows-scheduler-to-check-file-exist-then-execute-a-script-till-process-is-finished-then?forum=w7itprogeneral). Could anyone give me any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: What is "task scheduler to detect a file"? Please explain.

Comment: @harrymc That means that if a file exists in the directory that task scheduler is pointed to, something will happen.

Comment: No.. you can fire up a task and see if it is there.. or you can run a process (all of the time) that watches for the file to arrive.

Comment: The question I have would be how quickly do you need to know the file exists?  Can you poll for it or do you need to know straight away?  Google filesystemwatcher.if you need to know straight away.

Answer (score 0):

You may shedule to run a batch (`.bat`) that may contain such code:

```
if exist <insert file name here> (
    rem file exists
) else (
    rem file doesn't exist
)
```

Or in a single line for a single action:

```
if exist <insert file name here> <action>
```

For more information and examples see the
[IF command](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html).